# Hourly trigger is causing email alert to be sent hourly but only first time is needed

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a script which checks for two things:

-> Row with today's date in column D AND associated value in column F to be greater than 0.5. When these are both true, it sends out an email alert.

However, I set my Google Script Trigger for this script to be every hour. Now, when this condition is true it sends me an alert every hour. I want to be alerted only the FIRST time (i.e. the First hour) this condition was detected for a given day.

So, instead of receiving 24 emails for the day (every hour of that day), I only want to get the FIRST email. How can this be added to this script?

```
function readCell() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('test'); 
  var rg=sh.getDataRange()
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var yesterday=new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(),new Date().getDate());//today
  var yesterdayString=Utilities.formatDate(yesterday, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMddyyyy")

  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if (isDate(vA[i][2])) {
      var t1=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(vA[i][2]),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MMddyyyy");//

      if(t1==yesterdayString && Number(vA[i][5])>0.5) {
        MailApp.sendEmail('blabla@gmail.com','Alert!', 'Detected on: ' +vA[i][3].)

      }
    }
  }
}
function isDate(date){
  return(Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]');
}
```

Comment: That is what the daily timer is for?

Comment: Yes, the daily timer to to detect if the condition is met but once it is met on a given day, it should only send an alert 1 time. Right now, i get one alert email every hour when the first one would have been sufficient. Can you help?

Comment: You need to add a column to keep a record of rows that have already generated an email won't do it again or you could delete the row. Your yesterday is actually today.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Adding a new column and flagging the row that has been already detected is great. Then, I just need to add that additional flag logic into the script. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: If you don't want to maintain the record in the spreadsheet, where it could be accidently deleted, you might want to checkout the [GAS Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/) or [Cache Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/).